# Stream live video in openCv from localHost port (http://192.168.1.1:8080)

Tags: android, opencv

How can i make a live stream in openCv, knowing that an android device stream his camera preview at local host http://192.168.4.185:8095, and the encoding is h264.
So if i type in browser of the computer "http://192.168.4.185:8095" i will see the live video camera from android device. How can i get this live video to openCv either?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a VideoCapture, and open it with the path as "http://device_ip:port".